# Which happens first? The daily upgrade or the midnight attack?

Tags: die2nite

Title pretty much says it all. Which one takes place first? It would be pretty handy to know with the great pit upgrades and how much defense you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [help page](http://www.die2nite.com/#help?id=upgrades&short=1;sk=03c9f):

> Just before the midnight attack, the upgrade which has received the most votes is accepted and constructed immediately.

So, it happens **before** the attack, making the Great Pit upgrade useful if you need that one edge.

Answer (score 5):

The upgrades happen before the nightly attack, so you can count them in your defense estimate.

Disclaimer: This holds true for the german version of Die2Nite, I'm assuming it is the same for the english one